# Is the address of a buffer equal to the buffer?

Tags: c, pointers

I had two different codes:

```
uint8_t buf[10];
writeSomeDataInto(&buf);
readSomeDataFrom(buf);
```

and it was working correctly, but then I realized that I was sendind the address of the buffer, not the buffer itself, and changed it to:

```
uint8_t buf[10];
writeSomeDataInto(buf);
readSomeDataFrom(buf);
```

and the result was exactly the same.

Why am I getting the same result? Is `&buf` and `buf` the same thing in this context? It is actually does not make sense to me that the compiler would allocate some space for the buffer pointer `&buf` address.

How is this different from the code below?

```
uint8_t * ptr;
writeDataInto(&ptr); //actually  sending the pointer of a pointer.
readDataFrom(ptr);
```

Comparing it also with pointer to functions such as `"void myfunc(); //myfunc == &myfunc`

I feel that I'm missing some concept about how C works.